# Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a query regarding this error that appears to me. I'm trying to call an APIREST service with RestTemplate but I can't understand why it happens or how to solve it. I hope you can direct me.

I have the following screenshot, as you can see, it sends an error with Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.Object;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
[image]

This is what the link to which I want to get your information shows:

[image]

I must mention that the link that is commented out from jsonplaceholder does work without problems.....

Comment: From what you posted, the API returns JSON data, but the code does not handle JSON at all. Look up how to parse JSON data into Java objects. Also, please do not post screenshots of text.